# Python plot histogram based on date (datetime64)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a csv dataframe that I've reduced to two columns; `uploadDate` and `clubName`.

`uploadDate` has been set to datetime64.

I would like to query the dataframe for all rows with a particular `clubName` and then take all of the associated dates into a histogram so that I can see how many uploads there were per day. This is what I'm doing:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('query_result_2022-08-04T20_11_46.398221Z.csv', usecols=[9, 10], infer_datetime_format=True)
df.rename({'Uploaded Date Time': 'uploadDate', 'Club Name': 'clubName'}, axis=1, inplace=True)


df["uploadDate"] = df["uploadDate"].astype("datetime64")

cruiseDates = df.query('clubName == "DM1368-20220521"')
```

Print `cruiseDates` is outputting:

|  | uploadDate | clubName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-05-03 22:39:05.428173 | DM368-20220521 |
| 1 | 2022-05-03 22:38:20.188380 | DM368-20220521 |
| 2 | 2022-05-04 22:37:36.959855 | DM368-20220521 |
| 3 | 2022-05-08 22:32:43.913769 | DM368-20220521 |
| 4 | 2022-05-08 22:32:07.081055 | DM368-20220521 |

**How best to build the histogram and data?**

I've explored removing the time as below, but it stopped being a datetime then.

`df['uploadDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['uploadDate'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").dt.date`

I've also looked at grouping dates, to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```py
df["uploadDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["uploadDate"])
df.groupby(df["uploadDate"].dt.date).size()
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks!
Having adapted that, I've now got the below (which is great):
2022-05-09    376
2022-05-10    206
2022-05-11     63
2022-05-12     42
2022-05-13     49
2022-05-14     37
2022-05-15     39
2022-05-16     76
2022-05-17     81
2022-05-18     59
2022-05-19     19
2022-05-20     40
2022-05-21     50

Any thoughts on how I convert it to an x and y axis?

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: you need  .set_index("uploadDate")  It will set the date as the index。Sorry, I'm on vacation this weekend, so I didn't reply in time